# PHP and js fetch Unexpected token < in JSON error in localhost

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fetch

I know there are a few question about this topic. I applied at them but I still get this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

this code works other APIs

```
getData() {
  fetch('http://localhost:50/data', {
    headers : {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
     }
  })
  .then((response) => { return response.json(); })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

php code

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(['data' => 'test']);
```

Comment: your localhost server is likely throwing an html error.  try using your browser's inspector and watch the network request response, you should be able to see what you're getting back.  generally this is due to php giving a warning or error in html tags before the response.

Comment: I see it's a CORS request. Does your server side process CORS pre-flight? (which is triggered by the content-type header)

Answer (score 0):

That unexpected `<` probably means you got back HTML instead of JSON. Log the response and read it, it may be an error message from your server.

Comment: I can get json output from the url

Answer (score -2):

[Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) has a good guide for using fetch, especially for beginners.

I actually just faced with the same problem earlier and after searching for a few hours with no luck, so I experimented on it and finally got it working.

I copy pasted the sample codes on Developer Mozilla with the complete initialized values for the object after the url

```
fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // must match 'Content-Type' header
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, same-origin, *omit
    headers: {
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
```

and it worked, so I tried removing each property to see if removing it will cause the error again and I found out that removing the `credentials: 'same-origin` will cause the error I experienced earlier.

You forgot to put a `method: 'GET'` on your code. Your final code should look like this. Hope it helps.

```
  fetch('http://localhost:50/data', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers : {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
     }
  })
  .then((response) => { return response.json(); })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: Honestly I think it would be great to at least add some comments upon down voting, I'm not a pro so any comment on what is wrong with my answer would be helpful